# System Hangs by writing delay after Timer_init()

Tags: c, pic

I am facing a strange issue while programming PIC18f45k22. I am initiating system modules and then I write a blocking delay for 3 seconds to wait for a touch screen to start (because I need to send some information to this screen). But when I do this I discovered that when I initiate timer before writing the delay, I discover that the system freezes.
This is the code that I used
NOTE: all the functions work fine without any problem.

```
void main(void) { 
    Sys_Init(); 
     __delay_ms(3000);
   
 while(1){
//Code
}
```

System initiation code

```
void Sys_Init(void) {
     Delay_XTAL(); 
     OSCILLATOR_Init();
     DIGITAL_PIN_STATE();
     ANALOG_PIN_STATE();
     ADC_INIT(); //change clock select pins when oscillator changes
     Spi_Init(); 
     DHT22_init();
     Uart_Init(9600); //initiate UART (change baud values when oscillator value changed)
     Timer1_Init(); //initiate timer one (change prescaler and counter value if oscillator value changes)
}
```

Timer code

```
void Timer1_Init(void){ //for interrupt program use this function
//Prescaler 1:1; TMR1 Preload = 61536; Actual Interrupt Time : 1 ms
T1CON = 0x01;
TMR1IF = 0;
TMR1H = 0xF0;
TMR1L = 0x60;
TMR1IE = 1;
INTCON = 0xC0;
}
```

Interrupt code

```
void __interrupt() ISR (void){
    Timer1();
    
    }

void Timer1(void){  //for interrupt program
      if (TMR1IF){
   cnt1++;
    TMR1H    = 0xF0; //overflow every 1 ms
    TMR1L    = 0x60;
   TMR1IF = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that it stucks in the interrupt. You're supposed to implement interrupt service routine cause you enable the timer interrupt and then global and peripheral interrupts, have you implemented it?

Comment: Yes, I did, as I need to implement several tasks at specific timing

Comment: Do you clear TMR1IF in your interrupt routine? Or maybe any other interrupt source that you don't handle and clear its flag?

Comment: I have edited the question to include the interrupt part

Comment: There are no signs of error related to your question. You use some serial hardware; if their interrupts are enabled and this is all your interrupt service routine, then the way you handle interrupts is a little weird. It's better to check interrupt flags first, and then call the related handler function if needed. But you first call the handler and check the flag within the handler. As a result; the information you've provided is not enough to detect the error. If you've used any other interrupts, you should provide the whole interrupt code.

Comment: The timer interrupt is used to apply a timing delay between tasks through the (cnt) counter (as it counts every overflow), and I have to clear the interrupt flag after each overflow to prevent hanging of the system. And even if I checked the flag first, this will not change anything. The only additional interrupt used is the UART interrupt for receiving codes (and it works without emerging this problem).